# Drawing a circle tangential to 3 circles (internally to one of them)

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

[image: the image]

The two small circles (in black) are equal in radius, and tangential to the large circle. They also touch each other at the center of the large circle.
Now, I want to construct a circle (in orange) which is tangential to the inner two, and the larger circle.
How can I construct it?

Comment: In general, this is known as the [problem of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius).

Comment: But that problem considers three circles which are not touching or intersecting with each other, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, for instance see the section "Mutually tangent given circles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it by my own. Hoping there are no mistakes.

Draw a line from the center of the orange circle to the center of the lower small circle. Call the angle from this line the horizontal $\alpha$.

Call the radius of the smaller circle $r$ and the radius of the biggest circle $1$. The radius of the smaller black circles is then obviously $1/2$.

Then you get two equations (from horizontal and vertical distances):
$$1=r+(r+1/2)\cos\alpha$$
$$(r+1/2)\sin\alpha=1/2$$
Solving them you get $r=1/3$.

This can be easly constructed:

Draw a horizontal line through the blue center of the big circle and divide it by three. You know how? Then you have the Center of your circle.

**[Edit]**
I used the identity $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$. You can skip the step with the angle $\alpha$ and use directly the pythagoras. Which leads to the same.

Comment: I used the trigometric pythagoras $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$. Which leads to the same ;)

Comment: That works well! And yes, using Pythagoras Theorem is much simpler.